# Does my rose flower have another flower bud in it?

Tags: flowers, botany

[image]
[image]

Title says it all... what's going on with my rose flower?

[Update]: The inside flower has now also opened!
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, although it looks as if it's not actually going to flower. It's a phenomenon known as proliferation, and it can happen in a range of plants, though it seems to be a little more common in roses. Usually, it's only one or two blooms that may be affected in this way, and subsequent flowers are normal, with no proliferation. Thought to be a temporary genetic blip, a brief mutation in that particular flower, possibly caused by physical injury (such as a late frost) or with no obvious cause. Further info here https://www.rhs.org.uk/problems/mutations-flower-proliferation